# How to create a CLI for Wolfram language scripts?

Tags: scripting, command-line, parsing, arguments

> Former question: How to use wolframscript to develop flexible command-line tools?

I am currently changing a notebook into a wolframscript for a "production" environment,
where I plan to pack the script as a standard CLI tool.
However I do not know how to implement such an interface,
where boolean, switch-like, argument accepting and other sorts of options are supported.

In `bash` `python` and many other scripting languages, either the parsing functionality is built-in,
or there exists (semi-)official parsing modules for this purpose, named `getopt` `argparse` or similar.

As of my knowledge and of Jan 2021, there is no such libraries for wolframscript yet. The [`GetOpts` package by](https://github.com/McSaks/GetOpts) [@McSaks](https://github.com/McSaks), a candidate for this, has been out of maintenance for years, and no longer suffice modern needs.

There does exist a `-args` option in the grammar, supplied to the executed command,
after the main `-c|-f|-api|-fun` parameter for the interpreter
(which did not seem to exist when the related questions on SE were asked).
But it is *de facto* not documented, thus leaving me confused.

---

### Related resources

Based on the [answer by](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/239673) [@Mr Puh](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/49157/mr-puh), I think the wording of my question may not be clear enough, and the following resources may be helpful for discussion:

1. [C library function `getopt` - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopt)
2. [C++ `Boost.Program_options`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/program_options.html)
3. [Built-in Unix shell command `getopts` - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Getopts)
4. [Python 3 standard library | `getopt` — C-style parser for command line options](https://docs.python.org/3/library/getopt.html) (not recommended)
5. [Python 3 standard library | `argparse` — Parser for command-line options, arguments and sub-commands](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html)
6. [Python 3 HOWTOs | Argparse Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/argparse.html)
7. [Google Commandline Flags](https://github.com/gflags/gflags)
8. [C++ 3rd party library `argparse`](https://github.com/p-ranav/argparse) by [@p-ranav](https://github.com/p-ranav)
9. [Haskell command line option parsers](http://wiki.haskell.org/Command_line_option_parsers)

### Related questions (sorted by relevance)

1. [Passing arguments into a script in WolframScript](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/192320)
2. [Creating flags to use with wolframscript?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/199476)
3. [Parse command line arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/146993)
4. [Mathematica script - passing command line arguments](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5347)

---

Since this thread is not receiving extensive replies, I now wonder what is the best practice of `wolframscript`. What's the use intended by WRI? What's the most common official practice?

Comment: I would try to have the script interpret the argument as a Wolfram language expression.  For example, the user could pass a list of rules.

Comment: I'm not familiar with CLI but interested in the question, could you please add a hypothetical example on how would you like it to work or look like?

Comment: An ability to provide a local APIFunction seems good enough already. It contains all interpreter features for parsing any type of argument. So just `Put[APIFunction[...], LocalObject["yourscriptname"]]` and then `wolframscript -api yourscriptname -local -args x=1 y=string z='10 meters'`.

Comment: @swish Thanks a lot for this comment, the ability to pass arguments as an association is quite flexible. But since I am not familiar with APIFunctions, after some tweaking, I am still a little confused with their usage. Is it that only built-in or pure functions can be used in APIfunctions?

Comment: @swish Really sorry but I still have questions... I wonder how the Wolfram system recognizes a `LocalObject` as a API? We know that a `LocalObject` is a directory in the `$Path`, with a `object.wl` file and additional files with definitions. With the code you provided, there will be a `put.wl` which contains a singal `APIFunction` expression.

Answer (score 2):

Following the route suggested by [swish](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/2490/swish), I ended up modifying the `LocalObject` file created by `Put`. The reason is that my script contains several delayed definitions that are otherwise evaluated by `Put`.

Here's an example of the content of a `LocalObject["example"]` data-file:

```
(* Definition added later *)
f[number_, name_] := "Hello " <> name <> "! Your number is: " <> number

(* This was created by Put[APIFunction[...], LocalObject["example"]] *)
APIFunction[{"number"->"String","name"->"String"}, f[#number, #name]& ]
```

which can later be called with `wolframscript -api example -local -args name='Pippo' number=31`.

I'm sure there's a better way of writing an expression unevaluated without having to manually edit the local object file. I tried with `HoldForm` – or `ToExpression[expr, InputForm, Hold]` –  but then one should use `ReleaseHold` to evaluate the expression and, honestly, I don't know how to do it inside the script.

Answer (score -1):

As there are no answers yet, I'd like to share how I use wolframscript from the command line, please correct me if I am wrong.

Here are two possibilities I know of:

#### Converting a notebook to a script

1. You create a notebook (.nb), convert all the cells relevant to initialization cells and save it as an .m file.
2. You can use `wolframscript -script scriptname arg1 arg2 arg3` now and arg1 will be available as within the script as `$ScriptCommandLine[[2]]]`. Also check [this documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/$ScriptCommandLine.html).

#### Use python

There is a [wolframlanguage plugin](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/WolframClientForPython/index.html) for python now. You can use this to call functions in the namespace of one of your [wolfram packages](https://reference.wolfram.com/workbench/index.jsp?topic=/com.wolfram.eclipse.help/html/tasks/applications/packages.html).
So first write a package, then in python do something like this:

```python
from wolframclient.evaluation import WolframLanguageSession
from wolframclient.language import wl

with WolframLanguageSession() as s:

    # Locate the mathematica package to install
    s.evaluate(wl.SetDirectory(s.evaluate(wl.Directory())+path_to_mathematica_m))
    s.evaluate(wl.Import("YOUR_PACKAGE.m"))
    
    # This calls the wolfram language function with arguments
    output_expression = wl.YOUR_PACKAGE.Function1(an_array.tolist(),arg2,arg3)

    output = s.evaluate(output_expression)

    # Then do something with the output. E.g. Export it to a file:
    s.evaluate(wl.Export(exportpath,output))
```

This allows you to use the wolframlanguage via python and thus you can use all the tools you have for python also for the wolframlanguage.

Comment: (Former comment edited) Thank you for  your reply but I think you may be beside the point. My intention is to use the `wolframscript` interpreter (not `python` or others as such) from the OS shell upon a `.wls` script, and provide it with a Unix-like (preferably bash oriented) CLI, i.e., systematic `man` construction, named (keyword), optional, switch and array parameters and other stuff.

Comment: Official documentation only allow positional command-line arguments for local user defined scripts. This is sufficient if the script merely contains a simple function, but is found wanting for more sophisticated circumstances.

Comment: I personally have been using the python invocation approach for a while now, but compicated invocations are hard to debug and error-prone. As you can see, this situation can be greatly improved if the WLS script have a flexible CLI.